# cant connect to Datastax OpsCenter after brand new install

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Can anyone help, I did a fresh install of Datastax OpsCenter/Lifecylce Manager, installed via apg-get on clean Ubuntu VMs. But, I can not connect via browser, "site not found", on port 8888.

ps returns a running process and Status seems started.  Any ideas?

> root@unigmadevdse1:/var/log/opscenter# ps -ef | grep opscenter root
>   19381  1890  0 20:49 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto opscenter
>
> root@unigmadevdse1:/var/log/opscenter# service opscenterd status ●
>   opscenterd.service - LSB: Cassandra cluster manager    Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/init.d/opscenterd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)    Active:
>   active (exited) since Tue 2017-03-07 20:39:54 UTC; 9min ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)   Process: 18848 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/opscenterd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Mar 07 20:39:53 unigmadevdse1.unigmagroup.com systemd[1]: Starting
>   LSB: Cassandra cluster manager...
>
> Mar 07 20:39:54 unigmadevdse1.unigmagroup.com systemd[1]: Started LSB: >Cassandra cluster manager.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the `opscenter.log` file for any error messages [if you are not sure, run a `find / -iname opscenter.log`

or try a `service opscenter start -f` [will output to screen]

Comment: The log is empty..service opscenterd start -f doesnt output to the screen:
root@unigmadevdse1:/var/log/opscenter# service opscenterd start -f
root@unigmadevdse1:/var/log/opscenter#